# How is damage calculated in Disgaea 2?

Tags: disgaea-2

The only relevant information I could find is [this post](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/930240-disgaea-2-cursed-memories/43146509) which says:

> For normal attacks against an enemy with 0 DEF:
>
> Base = (Attack_Stat(s) / 3) * (1 + Crit_Chance + Combo_Bonus) * Position * Class_Bonus
>
> DMG = Base * [1.00 ~ 1.20 in 0.01 increments]

I assume `Attack_Stats(s)` refers to the mean of stats connected to abilities/weapons. I do not know what `Position`, `Class_Bonus` and `Combo_Bonus` are numerically. This is also ignoring defence, which is the main reason I want to find the formula.

From reading various threads it seems given a fixed attacker strength there is an amount of defence where you will take zero damage. I only mention this because some games have minimum damage or diminishing returns on defence.

Comment: I know that "Position" is 1.0, 1.1 or 1.2 for front, flank and rear respectively.

Comment: I would presume "Class_Bonus" refers to any character ability that boosts damage directly - for example Adell's 25% bonus damage against higher levels would translate to 1.25 in the formula.